# adapting a css animation to different screen size

Tags: html, css, animation, responsive-design, width

Consider the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/ytup9tpq/) scrolling animation:

```
<div style="height:50px;width:50%;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid red;"><img id="test" style="width:100%;position:relative;top:0px;border:3px solid black" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"></div>
<style>
#test {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s linear 0s infinite alternate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst 3s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    from {top:0;}
    to {top:-200px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    from {top:0;}
    to {top:-200px;}
} 
</style>
```

I need to move the image up and down inside its div container so that it reverses the scrolling direction when the image bottom reaches the div bottom. To this aim, I can set a proper `to top:` value in the animation parameters.

However, the div container has a percentual width, and so even the image width scales according to screen size. How can I adjust my code to make the animation working on devices with different width?

Comment: Can't you just use percentage tops as well for the animation?

Comment: No, I have a fixed height and the width in percent units. So it does not work to set percentage top for height.